# Error reading timestamps using "xlsx" package

Tags: r, time-series, xlsx, posixct

Data in Excel file looks like

```
TIMESTAMP           TYPE BID BIDSIZ
2015-01-04 09:00:00 BID 365    10
2015-04-01 09:00:05 BID 367.8  55
2015-04-01 09:00:33 BID 365    10
2015-04-01 09:00:36 BID 367.8  55
```

When I run the following code:

```
require(xlsx)
f1<-read.xlsx2("Canara_Data.xlsx", sheetName = "BID")
f1$TIMESTAMP<-as.POSIXct(f1$TIMESTAMP, format="%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:S")
```

viewing it causes TIMESTAMP to look like

```
View(`f1`)

TIMESTAMP   X.  BID BIDSIZ
42008.375   BID 365 10
42095.37505787037   BID 367.8   55
42095.37538194445   BID 365 10
42095.37541666667   BID 367.8   55

str(f1)
# 'data.frame': 18214 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ TIMESTAMP: POSIXct, format: NA NA ...
#  $ TYPE   : Factor w/ 1 level "BID": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ BID    : Factor w/ 344 levels "365","365.1",..: 1 55 1 55 1 55 1 55 59 1 ...
#  $ BIDSIZ : Factor w/ 1259 levels "1","10","100",..: 2 854 2 854 2 854 2 854 4 2
```

Please help in making TIMESTAMP to be read as date with the format "%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:S", and also BID and BIDSIZ as character.

Comment: Try the readxl package

Comment: @hadley Did you give the downvote? (I suspect you did as the timestamps of the downvote and your comment are approximately at the same time) If so, could you explain why? The answer works.

Comment: @hadley..Many thanks for the information regarding readxl package. This is just awesome. This is a recent package. So, I was not having much information on this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Package `readxl`

```
excel_sheets("C:\\Users\\Gaurav Kumar\\Documents\\Canara_Data.xlsx")
grv<-read_excel("C:\\Users\\Gaurav Kumar\\Documents\\Canara_Data.xlsx", sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)
```

and it will read the Timestamps too. It saves huge time in converting the excel to csv, knowing CSV has a problem in saving timestamps.

```
              TIMESTAMP EX  BID BIDSIZ
1   2015-04-01 09:00:00 N   365.00  10
2   2015-04-01 09:00:05 N   367.80  55
3   2015-04-01 09:00:33 N   365.00  10
4   2015-04-01 09:00:36 N   367.80  55
5   2015-04-01 09:00:41 N   365.00  10
6   2015-04-01 09:00:41 N   367.80  55
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel & date formats are often not a good combination. You can use:

```
f1$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(f1$TIMESTAMP*86400, origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT")
```

to convert it to a datatime format.

This gives:

```
> f1
            TIMESTAMP  X.   BID BIDSIZ
1 2015-01-04 09:00:00 BID 365.0     10
2 2015-04-01 09:00:05 BID 367.8     55
3 2015-04-01 09:00:33 BID 365.0     10
4 2015-04-01 09:00:36 BID 367.8     55
```

Another solution is to export your excel-file to a `.csv` or a tab-separated `.txt` file and then read it into R.

You can convert the `BID` and `BIDSIZ` columns to character columns with:

```
f1[,c(3:4)] <- lapply(f1[,c(3:4)], as.character)
```

---

Used data:

```
f1 <- structure(list(TIMESTAMP = c(42008.375, 42095.3750578704, 42095.3753819444, 42095.3754166667),
                     X. = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BID", class = "factor"), 
                     BID = c(365, 367.8, 365, 367.8),
                     BIDSIZ = c(10L, 55L, 10L, 55L)),
                .Names = c("TIMESTAMP", "X.", "BID", "BIDSIZ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Dear it is showing the - Error in Ops.POSIXt(f1$TIMESTAMP, 86400) : 
  '*' not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Comment: @gauravkumar It works on my system (R3.2.1 on OSX) with the data you provided. Did you use the exact same command? Could you else show your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Dear..this is a huge data..around 15000 data points. This can not be fit in structure.

Comment: Sessionnfo()R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] timeDate_3012.100 xlsx_0.5.7        xlsxjars_0.6.1    rJava_0.9-7      
[5] highfrequency_0.4 xts_0.9-7         zoo_1.7-12

Comment: @gauravkumar you can also do `dput(head(f1,10))` (and add that to your question, not in the comments)